# How to pipe multiple files into tesseract-ocr from a loop

Tags: bash, pipe, tesseract

I am looking to find a way to sequentially add files (PNG input files) to a ocr'ed PDF (via tesseract-3).
The idea is to scan a PNG, optimize it (optipng) and feed it via a stream to tesseract, which adds it to a ever growing PDF.
The time between scans is 20-40 seconds, and the scans go into the hundreds, which is why I want to use the wait time between the scans to do the OCR already.

I imagine this to work like this:

```
while ! $finished
do
  get_scanned_image_to_png_named_scannumber
  optipng $scannumber.png
  check_for_finishing_condition #all this works fine already
  sleep 30s
  #do some magic piping into a single tesseract instance here
done #or here?
```

The inspiration for this comes from here:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#how-to-ocr-streaming-images-to-pdf-using-tesseract

Thanks very much for any hint,

Joost

Edits:

OS: OpenSuse Tumbleweed

Scan: more of a series of "image aquisitions" resulting in a single PNG each (not a real scanner); going on for several hours at least.

FollowUp:
This kind of works when doing

```
while ! $finished
do
  get_scanned_image_to_png_named_scannumber
  optipng $scannumber.png
  check_for_finishing_condition #all this works fine already
  sleep 30s

  echo "$capnum.png"

done | tesseract -l deu+eng -c stream_filelist=true - Result pdf
```

, though the PDF is corrupted when you try to open it in between scan additions or stop this loop with e.g. Ctrl-C. I do not see a way to get an uncorrupted PDF.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. Are you scanning a new image each time through the loop? Why are you optimising the PNG before sending it to tesseract? It won't care whether the image is optimised or not. Are you creating one or two PDFs altogether - is one PDF full of PNGs and the other full of the OCRed text? What is the objective that you are trying to optimise the time to process? What OS are you using?

Comment: HI, yes, a new image each loop iteration. Optimising the PNGs shrinks file size 30-40% in my case/source files. One PDF with hundreds of pages as the final result. All this on Linux (sorry, forgot other OSes exist ;-)

Comment: Also, I hope that streaming every new image into tesseract enables the PDF to be already readable while the scanning process is still ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while ! $finished
do
  get_scanned_image_to_png_named_scannumber
  optipng $scannumber.png
  check_for_finishing_condition #all this works fine already
  sleep 30s
done | tesseract -c stream_filelist=true - - pdf > output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good start! Right now I get this: `Error in findFileFormatStream: failed to read first 12 bytes of file
Error in pixReadStream: Unknown format: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Image file  cannot be read!
Error during processing.
`. Do I need to "cat" the image file in the while loop somehow? Right now it just gets stored to disk.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is what I get for a single run:   `cat 131.png | tesseract -c stream_filelist=true - - pdf > test.pdf
Error in fopenReadStream: file not found
Error in pixRead: image file not found: �PNG
Image file �PNG cannot be read!
Error during processing.
`

Comment: tesseract expected the filename, not the content! Use `echo 131.png`

Comment: Yes, thanks, found that one as well. As mentioned in updated main post above, the problem is that I can not find a way to end the OCR process and get a working PDF (which is not corrupted)...